# How to calculate inverse using cramer's rule in python?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-inverse

I'm trying to generate the inverse matrix using numpy package in python. Unfortunately , I'm not getting the answers I expected.

Original matrix:

`([17 17 5]
 [21 18 21]
 [2 2 19])`

Inverting the original matrix by Cramer's rule gives:

`([4 9 15]
 [15 17 6]
 [24 0 17])`

Apparently using `numpy.linalg.inv()`  gives

`-3.19488818e-01,3.80191693e-01,-6.38977636e-03,
3.33333333e-01, -3.33333333e-01, 2.26123699e-18, 
-2.84345048e-01, 2.68370607e-01, 5.43130990e-02n`

I expected that multiplying the original matrix and the inverse would have given an identity matrix but as you can see I give a matrix filled with floating points.

Where can be the issue?

Comment: I don't think your application of Cramer's rule can possibly have given the correct inverse matrix here (what do you get if you multiply it by the original matrix?)

Comment: `array([[  1.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   1.05471187e-15],
      [  1.11022302e-16,   1.00000000e+00,  -7.21644966e-16],
      [  1.38235777e-17,   5.65818009e-18,   1.00000000e+00]])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may have made a mistake when inverting the matrix by hand.

When I perform the following

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[17, 17, 5], [21, 18, 21], [2, 2, 19]], dtype=np.float)
inv = np.linalg.inv(a)

print np.dot(inv, a)
```

I get

```
array([[  1.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00,   1.05471187e-15],
       [  1.11022302e-16,   1.00000000e+00,  -7.21644966e-16],
       [  1.38235777e-17,   5.65818009e-18,   1.00000000e+00]])
```

Which is fine, note that all the off diagonal elements are approximately zero to machine precision so it looks like numpy is doing an ok job with this one!

Remember that floating point numbers don't work like real numbers and you can expect small rounding errors to creep into your calculations unless you are careful.

---

If you want to do this exactly have a look at [sympy](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) which will be able to do the calculation with exact maths (at the expense of it being a little slower).

```
import sympy as sp

a = sp.Matrix([[17, 17,5],[21,18,21],[2,2,19]])
inv = a.inv()

print inv
print a * inv
```

yielding the exact inverse

```
Matrix([
[-100/313,  1/3, -89/313],
[ 119/313, -1/3,  84/313],
[  -2/313,    0,  17/313]])
```

which when multiplied by the original matrix gives the exact identity as you would expect

```
Matrix([
[1, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 0],
[0, 0, 1]])
```

Comment: i'm in a situation where i perform result=matrix* vectorA and result*inverse(matrix) should give vectorA exactly(encryption-decryption thing). But thats not happening due to the floating point numbers .Is there an alternative?

Comment: Numpy will only do matrix calculations on floating point numbers. It sounds like you need to calculate it using rationals. Have a look at [sympy](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) which should be able to do this for you.

Comment: I've edited my answer to give an example of doing the same thing in sympy for you.

Comment: i did try sympy and it worked ..yeah!! ..but with the new library i miss the convenience of numpy's modulo operator..but i guess one can't expect everything..

Comment: i solved that by converting my sympy matrix to numpy array , does leaving dtype as object cause any problem?

Comment: The only issue I can forsee is that it will make numpy's array operations slower as it cannot just drop back into optimized c for everything.

Answer (score 0):

`linalg` is right and you are wrong.

The matrix it gave you is indeed the inverse. However, if you are using `np.array` instead of `np.matrix` then the multiplication operator doesn't work as expected, since it calculates the component-wise product.

In that case you have to do `mat.dot(inv(mat))`.

In any case, what you will get will not be a perfect identity matrix due to rounding errors (when I tried it the off-diagonal matrix entries were in the order of `10 ** (-16)`).

Comment: i guess but i need this for encryption decryption purposes.due to the floating point numbers my results are deviating a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumed inverse is obviously wrong; the ones can only be achieved if some entries in the inverse matrix are smaller than one and the zeroes only if some entries are negative. I did not see what you are doing wrong, so I give an example. Using [Cramer's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule#Finding_inverse_matrix) you have e.g. for the first entry (18*19 - 2*21)/(-939) = -0.319... -- exactly what numpy found.